# NGINX proxy default cache time with Cache-Control and no expiration

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, cache

I have caching enabled on an NGINX proxy.

As I understand it, as long as I'm not ignoring the `Cache-Control` header in my proxy configuration (`proxy_ignore_headers`), the cache time before expiration can be set from the origin server using `Cache-Control` = `max-age=XXXX`.

But what would be the default cache time it would keep and use for something like `Cache-Control: public`? Is there a way to set a default maximum cache time for these resources?

Answer (score 5):

That is right, by default, with just `proxy_cache` configured, nginx only caches responses that have `max-age` set in the `Cache-Control` header.

Without any `Cache-Control` header or just `Cache-Control: public` nginx doesn't cache the response (i.e. you get each time `X-Cache-Status: MISS` when you also configure `add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;`).

You can configure a default caching time for responses without a `Cache-Control` header or ones without a `max-age` field in a `Cache-Control` header:

```
    # for 200, 301, 302 responses
    proxy_cache_valid     10m;
    # for all other responses
    proxy_cache_valid any 1m;
```

That means a `Cache-Control` header has precedence over a `proxy_cache_valid` setting and there are no defaults for `proxy_cache_valid`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is there any way to differentiate between the MISS because "no default set with proxy_cache_valid and no Cache-Control" that would not store the response and the MISS because "I will store this but its the first request"?

Answer (score 4):

You'd probably be better off setting or rewriting cache control headers inside Nginx. I have a tutorial on this [here](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-4-wordpress-website-optimization/#ccheaders), and part one of the tutorial has downloadable config files. The key parts are below

You need [headers_more](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module) for these to work. Some distributions include this, some don't and you need to build from source - which is pretty easy and is included in my tutorial.

**Copied from Tutorial**

We use a couple of different techniques to set cache control headers. First off we clear out any existing headers, like the very old Pragma which is not useful any more, clearing Expires headers (which is probably pointless since we set them later), and we clear the Server name for security.

```
more_clear_headers "Pragma"; more_clear_headers Server; more_clear_headers "Expires";
```

Then we can set the header manually. For image we use quite a long expires time

```
add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=691200, s-maxage=691200";
```

For pages we keep it shorter – many sites will need this much shorter

```
add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=86400, s-maxage=86400";
```

In some places we use an alternative format, for convenience.

```
expires 8d;
```

**Example Nginx Configuration**

An example Nginx server (with some parts missing like SSL setup)

```
# Caching. Putting the cache into /dev/shm keeps it in RAM, limited to 10MB, for one day.
# You can move to disk if you like, or extend the caching time
```

fastcgi_cache_path /dev/shm/nginxcache levels=1:2 keys_zone=CACHE:50m 
    inactive=1440m; #RAM

```
# This needs to match your PHP configuration. Port is sometimes 9000 ****
upstream php {
  server 127.0.0.1:9001;
}

server {
  server_name www.example.com;
  listen 443 ssl http2;

  root /var/www/***folder;

    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js|ico|svg)$ { 
  log_not_found off; access_log off;

    # Set up caching - 8 days for static resources
    # Remove the old unnecessary Pragma and hide the server version
    more_clear_headers "Cache-Control";
    add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=691200, s-maxage=691200";
    more_clear_headers Server; more_clear_headers "Pragma"; mo  re_clear_headers "Expires";
}


  # PHP requests
  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass   php;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

    # Use the cache defined above. Cache 200 (success) status's, for 24 hours, and cache
    # specific other status's for an hour. This helps mitigate DDOS attacks.
    # Only cache GET and HEAD requests
    fastcgi_cache CACHE;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 200 1440m;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 403 404 405 410 414 301 302 307 60m;
    add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

    fastcgi_cache_methods GET HEAD; 
    fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
    fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;

    # Set the cache control headers we prepared earlier. Remove the old unnecessary Pragma and hide
    # the server version. Clearing existing headers seems necessary
    more_clear_headers "Cache-Control";
    add_header Cache-Control $cacheControl;
    more_clear_headers "Pragma"; more_clear_headers Server; more_clear_headers "Expires";
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't edit at the moment, but want to say that `fastcgi_cache_path` must be put in the same file as the rest of the configuration, but outside of the `server {}` directive.